# How can I programmatically deselect an item in a selector (or checkbox) when a specific one is selected?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I haven't decided yet on whether I'm going to use a Select (listbox when set to allow multiple) or a set of checkboxes, but in either case one of the values the user can select is "All"; that is the only value selected/checked by default, but if the user selects/checks any of the other values, I want the "All" value to become deselected/unchecked. Also, if subsequently the user selects the All item/checkbox, I want to deselect/uncheck all the others. I assume this is a job for jQuery, but don't know how to accomplish it...

### Update

In response to jQueryRocks' proposed answer:

With this html:

```
    <td>
        <select name="siteSelector" id="siteSelector" multiple="multiple" size="6">
            <option value="all" selected="selected" id="selectAll">All</option>
            <option class="options" value="1">1</option>
            <option class="options" value="2">2</option>
            <option class="options" value="3">3</option>
            <option class="options" value="16">16</option>
            <option class="options" value="26">26</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

...and this jQuery (I'm showing *all* of it, just for completeness' sake):

```
$(function () {
    AnyTime.picker("BeginDateTime");
    AnyTime.picker("EndDateTime");

$('#BeginDateTime').val(function(){
  var d = new Date();
  return d.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + " 00:00:00";
});

$('#EndDateTime').val(function(){
  var d = new Date();
  return d.getFullYear() + "-" + ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + " 23:59:59";
});

    $('input#selectAll').click(function() {
    if($(this).filter(':checked').val() !== undefined) {
        $('input.options').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('input.options').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

});
```

...I can still select "All" then something else, and "All" remains selected (when I Ctrl+click another value). Am I doing something wrong?

Based on your code, I tried changing my html to this:

```
    <td>
        <select name="siteSelector" id="siteSelector" multiple="multiple" size="6">
            <option value="all" selected="selected" id="selectAll">All</option>
            <option id="deselectAll" value="1">1</option>
            <option id="deselectAll" value="2">2</option>
            <option id="deselectAll" value="3">3</option>
            <option id="deselectAll" value="16">16</option>
            <option id="deselectAll" value="26">26</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

...and my (pertinent) jQuery to this:

```
$('input#deselectAll').click(function () {
        if ($(this).filter(':checked').val() !== undefined) {
            $('input#selectAll').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

...but that doesn't work, either.

### UPDATE 2

I also tried this to, for the checkbox extravaganza, no avail:

html:

```
<td>
    <INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="all">All
    <BR>
    <INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="1" id="options">1
    <BR>
    <INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="2" id="options">2
    <BR>
    <INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="3" id="options">3
    <BR>
    <INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="16" id="options">16
    <BR>
    <INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="26" id="options">26
    <BR>
</td>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input.options').click(function() {
    var allChecked = true;
    var allUnchecked = true;
    $('input.options').each(function() {
        if($(this).filter(':checked').val() === undefined) {
            allChecked = false;
        }
        else if($(this).filter(':checked').val() !== undefined) {
            allUnchecked = false;
        }
    });
    if(allChecked) {
        $('input#selectAll').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else if(allUnchecked) {
        $('input#selectAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

...so I replaced the jQuery with this:

```
$('input#options').click(function () {
        var anyOptionsChecked;
        $('input#options').each(function () {
            if ($(this).filter(':checked').val() !== undefined) {
                anyOptionsChecked = true;
            }
        });
        if (anyOptionsChecked) {
            $('input#selectAll').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

...but that doesn't work, either.

Should the "if ($(this).filter(':checked').val() !== undefined) {" line be instead:

```
if($(this).filter(':checked').val() == checked) {
```

-or:

```
if($(this).filter(':checked').val() === checked) {
```

-or something else altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is what you want to achieve, check this link as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/z5sCU/3/

**HTML**

```
<select name="siteSelector" id="siteSelector" multiple="multiple" size="6">
  <option class="options" value="all" >All</option>
  <option class="options" value="1">1</option>
  <option class="options" value="2">2</option>
  <option class="options" value="3">3</option>
  <option class="options" value="16">16</option>
  <option class="options" value="26">26</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#siteSelector').click(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.val() == 'all'){
        self.children().prop('selected',true).click()
    }
    else
    {
        self.find('.options:first').prop('selected', false)
    }
})
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

With checkboxes  http://jsfiddle.net/z5sCU/8/:

html:

```
<INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="all" class="options">All
<BR>
<INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="1" class="options">1
<BR>
<INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="2" class="options">2
<BR>
<INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="3" class="options">3
<BR>
<INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="16" class="options">16
<BR>
<INPUT NAME="sites" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="26" class="options">26
<BR>
```

Javascript:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
   var self = $(this);
   if (self.val() == 'all') {
       $('input[type=checkbox]').not(':first').prop('checked', false) //.click()
   } else {
       $('input[type=checkbox]:first').prop('checked', false)
   }
 })
```

**EDIT:**

Updated checkbox example not to use the same `id`'s for the checkboxes, because it is not a good practise to do it, instead changed it to `class`

Comment: Very cool; I do think the collection of checkboxes looks better than the unwieldy (could end up being quite tall) select element, so I will try to adapt this idea to that.

Comment: @Clay, also check this version: http://jsfiddle.net/z5sCU/5/ .. I think this one is what you wanted...

Comment: I actually like the earlier one better, because selecting "All" selects all of the other items.

Comment: @Clay, I'm glad it helped you and gave some direction. Check this link for the first behavoir, but for the checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/z5sCU/9/

Answer (score 1):

for selecting/deselecting all checkboxes, where the input with id "selectAll" turns inputs of class "options" on and off:

```
$('input#selectAll').click(function() {
    if($(this).filter(':checked').val() !== undefined) {
        $('input.options').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('input.options').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

And to handle selecting/deselecting "all" based on clicking single checkboxes

```
$('input.options').click(function() {
    var allChecked = true;
    var allUnchecked = true;
    $('input.options').each(function() {
        if($(this).filter(':checked').val() === undefined) {
            allChecked = false;
        }
        else if($(this).filter(':checked').val() !== undefined) {
            allUnchecked = false;
        }
    });
    if(allChecked) {
        $('input#selectAll').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else if(allUnchecked) {
        $('input#selectAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow; if it works (I reckon it will), I'll post-bounty this; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="groupedSites">
            <legend class="labelText">Select the Sites you want to include</legend>
            <input type="button" id="selectAllSites" name="selectAllSites" value="Select All" />
            <label for="site1">1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="site1" id="site1" />
            <label for="site2">2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="site2" id="site2" />
            <label for="site3">3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="site3" id="site3" />
            <label for="site16">16</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="site16" id="site16" />
            <label for="site26">26</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="site26" id="site26" />
            <input type="button" id="deselectAllSites" name="deselectAllSites" value="Deselect All" />
        </fieldset>
    </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#selectAllSites").click(function () {
        $('#groupedSites input').attr('checked', true);
    });

    $("#deselectAllSites").click(function () {
        $('#groupedSites input').attr('checked', false);
    });
```